# Vector drawing app with "partial erase" (raster-like)

Tags: windows, gratis, drawing, vector-graphics, svg

I'm looking for a ***free vector drawing app***, supporting ***MS Surface Pen***, with a feature where you can ***erase parts of lines*** by dragging the eraser over them. I mean an effect like if I was erasing a  part of a raster image/line, but on a vector image. The app must also be able to ***save and open SVG files***.

All the above features are hard requirements for me in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I somehow wasn't expecting it, but ***[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org)*** seems to mostly fit the bill! It generally **ticks all the boxes** in my original question.

[image]

A few **small disadvantages** with regards to *"MS Surface Pen support"* are that:

- it doesn't seem to have support for pen pressure sensitivity; or at least I couldn't find it (please correct me if I'm wrong!)
- navigation with fingers could be better (no panning, must workaround with zooming)
- doesn't seem to auto-detect if I'm using the drawing or erasing end of the MS Surface Pen (they both work the same in the app)

***edit:*** One **annoying disadvantage** I noticed soon afterwards is that, at least as of the version I tried, the drawing line doesn't start immediately when I start moving the Surface Pen, but only a small moment later. You can see this especially as I try to draw the second fragment of "hair" — the line is non-continuous, although I push the pen where the previous line ended. Also, a similar effect seems to be at work where I struggle to draw the pupil of the eye on your left. Not sure what's the reason and if it's possible to fix this. Haven't tested newer version of Inkscape yet either.